# How to detect crashes in unit testing using swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a class I wrote named "MyClass". What I want to test is a combination of different methods to see that the code is not crashing.

This is my test method:

```
func testMethod() {
    MyClass.methodA()
    MyClass.methodB()
    MyClass.methodC()
    MyClass.methodA()
    MyClass.methodC()
}
```

I thought about doing so with try-catch to elegantly fail the test if a catch happens, but my functions aren't throwing anything. So I need a different solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you don't do it this way. I recommend only testing for exceptions when you actually want to verify that some input causes an exception, and when you have a specific way you want the code to behave in these circumstances.

Testing that your code does NOT throw is redundant. Test that the code does what it's supposed to do instead.

If you want to test `int Add(int, int)`, if you test that `Add(1, 1) == 2`, you have implicitly tested that it doesn't throw. Your tests fail automatically if the code throws, so test something of actual value instead. Why do these methods exist? Why do you call them? There must be some kind of business value, so test that their purpose is filled.